# How can I redirect all output to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, pipe, output-redirect, dev-null

I want to run a program (`google-chrome`) in the background, but prevent it from outputting any messages to the terminal.

I tried doing this:

```
google-chrome 2>&1 1>/dev/null &
```

However, the terminal still fills up without messages like:

> [5746:5746:0802/100534:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(532)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.Mtpd.EnumerateStorag...

What am I doing wrong? How do I redirect **all** the output to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Redirection operators are evaluated left-to-right. You wrongly put `2>&1` first, which points `2` to the same place, as `1` currently is pointed to which is the local terminal screen, because you have not redirected `1` yet. You need to do either of the following:

```
2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null google-chrome &
```

Or

```
2>/dev/null 1>&2 google-chrome &
```

The placement of the redirect operators in relation to the command does not matter. You can put them before or after the command.

Comment: why do you use a trailing `&`?

Comment: Because the OP says they want to run the command in the background

Answer (score 52):

In the section *Redirection*, Bash's reference manual says:

> The operator `[n]>&word` is used [...] to duplicate output file descriptors

To redirect both standard error and standard output to `file` you should use the form

```
&>file
```

With regard to your case, that means substitute

```
2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

with

```
&>/dev/null
```

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1` is maybe more portable than `&>/dev/null`?

Comment: @Campa what does portable mean here? That the redirection with & will not work in some environments? If yes under what circumstances would it not work? Edit: Found my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434431/325410

Comment: Yep, exactly Nick, `&>` is bash jargon and will/might not work in other shells.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that syntax is different:

```
./a.out 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

See the devices for FD = 2 are different when `./a.out 1>/dev/null 2>&1` and `./a.out 2>&1 1>/dev/null &`

1) FD=2 points to /dev/null

```
>./a.out 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 21181
>lsof -p `pidof a.out`
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
a.out   21181 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    0u   CHR 136,43      0t0        46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   21181 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0      3685 /dev/null
a.out   21181 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0      3685 /dev/null
```

2) FD=2 points to /dev/pts/43

```
>./a.out 2>&1 1>/dev/null &
[1] 25955
>lsof -p `pidof a.out`
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
a.out   25955 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    0u   CHR 136,43      0t0        46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   25955 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0      3685 /dev/null
a.out   25955 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    2u   CHR 136,43      0t0        46 /dev/pts/43
```