# How to run a script in background (linux openwrt)?

Tags: linux, shell, ash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ] ; do
    urlfile=$( ls /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt | head -n 1 )
    dir=$( cat /root/wget/wget-dir.txt )
    if [ "$urlfile" = "" ] ; then
        sleep 30
        continue
    fi

    url=$( head -n 1 $urlfile )
    if [ "$url" = "" ] ; then
        mv $urlfile $urlfile.invalid
        continue
    fi

    mv $urlfile $urlfile.busy
    wget -b $url -P $dir -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -nc
    mv $urlfile.busy $urlfile.done
done
```

The script basically checks for any new URLs at `wget-download-link.txt` for every 30 seconds and if there's a new URL it'll download it with wget, the problem is that when I try to run this script on Putty like this

```
/root/wget/wget_download.sh --daemon
```

it's still running in the foreground, I still can see the terminal output. How do I make it run in the background ?

Comment: You can use the `&` operator at the end of your command to run it in the background.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 nohup /root/wget/wget_download.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It will go to the background so when you close your Putty session, it will be still running, and it won't send messages to the terminal.

Comment: although your process will start in background but still OP will see the output from script on terminal.

Comment: The complete command should be :

    nohup /root/wget/wget_download.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: I hadn't write it right the first time, so I edited it to add the /dev/null 2>&1.

It was my fault.

Comment: The accepted answer should be the (command) & solution.  There is no nohup on OpenWrt see this: http://bitzof.me/doku.php?id=electronics:wr703n:nohup

Answer (score 17):

In OpenWRT (before 2023) there is neither `nohup` nor `screen` available by default, so a solution with only builtin commands would be to start a subshell with brackets and put that one in the background with `&`:

```
(/root/wget/wget_download.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 )&
```

you can test this structure easily on your desktop for example with

```
(notify-send one && sleep 15 && notify-send two)&
```

... and then close your console before those 15 seconds are over, you will see the commands in the brackets continue execution after closing the console.

Comment: Just leaving this here, it's 2023, opkg has nohup: opkg install coreutils-nohup

Answer (score 2):

The following command will also work:

```
((/root/wget/wget_download.sh)&)&
```

This way you don't have to install the 'nohub' command in the tight memory space of the router used for OpenWrt.

I found this somewhere several years ago. It works.

Comment: could you explain why we need two `&`?

Comment: @AllanRuin There exist no reasons to have two `&`s.

Answer (score 1):

The `&`at the end of script should be enough, if you see output from the script it means, that `stdout` and/or `stderr` is not closed, or not redirect to `/dev/null`

You can use this answer:

[How to redirect all output to /dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024919/4009660)

Answer (score 1):

I am using openwrt merlin and the only way to get it working was using the crud cron manager[1]. Nohub and screen are not available as solutions.

> cru a pinggw "0 * * * * /bin/ping -c 10 -q 192.168.2.254"

works like charm

[1][https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-cron-job-on-asuswrt-merlin-wifi-router/]

Answer (score 1):

https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/coreutils-nohup

```
opkg update
opkg install coreutils-nohup
nohup yourscript.sh &
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nohup`.

```
nohup yourscript.sh
```

or

```
nohup yourscript.sh &
```

Your script will keep running even if you close your putty session, and all the output will be written to a text file in same directory.

nohup is often used in combination with the nice command to run processes on a lower priority.

```
nohup nice yourscript.sh &
```

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Answer (score 0):

For busybox in Openwrt Merlin system, I got a better solution which combined cru and date command

```
cru a YOUR_UNIQUE_CRON_NAME "`date -D '%s' +'%M %H %d %m *' -d $(( \`date +%s\`+2*60 ))` YOUR_CMD_HERE"
```

which add a cron job running 2 minutes later, and only run once.

Inspired by PlagTag's idea.

Answer (score 0):

In another way these code would tried:

```
ssh admin@192.168.1.1 "/jffs/your_script.sh &"
```

Simple and without any programs like nohup screen...
(BTW: worked on Asus-Merlin firmware)